# line breaks are not showing in the text

Tags: wordpress

I am adding text to a wordpress page and when I save the document the line breaks disappear. If I have two paragraphs sometimes they will stay in the second paragraph but disappear in the first. 
When I do inspect element the line breaks are showing but they are not showing on the actual page. You can see an example on 
[http://meornyu.org/israel](http://meornyu.org/israel#Itinerary)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' )
```

or
`remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' )` in your theme's functions.php
or you can even apply in the template for rendering content,
as `<?php echo wpautop(get_the_content());?>`

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can be a bit fussy with line breaks at times. Try wrapping your lines/paragraphs explicitly with `<p>`.

[Side Note] Conversely, sometimes Wordpress adds `<p>` tags where you did not enter them, in which case check out this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-automatic-p-tags/

Comment: You definitely don't need a plugin to disable `autop`

Comment: No you definitely don't, but that depends on who the user/site owner is and their level of comfort with going into the code. Someone who isn't comfortable with editing the code can just install the plugin.

Comment: how else would I disable autop? I think that might be the issue.

Comment: To disable autop you need to use the filter `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' )` or `remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' )` , depending on where you put it. See here: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Answer (score 0):

While entering content into text editor press the Shift and Enter key together to make a line break.Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add empty class attributes to your break elements.  For example

```
br class=“” instead of br
```